# What do you call someone who will talk bad about someone but tries to make it about you when they're called out?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

Toby calls Jetta ugly and gets embarrassed when Sarah calls him out and tells him that he should be nice to her because Jetta's done nothing to him.

Days later, Toby calls Sabah a bully for responding to the hate she received from another classmate.

Comment: Answers go in the answer box, please, not the comment box.